# Jquery show and hide shows one div but not another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use one href to show and hide two other divs. One div will show by default, but the second div still remains hidden.

```
    <a href="#ben1" class="fa fa fa-times closer" > 
    <p> link text </p>
   </a>
    <a href="#ben2" class="fa fa fa-times closer" > 
    <p> link text </p>
   </a>


<div class="resume right-col" id="ben1">
<p>Hello this is a test </p>
</div> 

<div class="resume right-col" id="ben2">
<p>Hello this is a test </p>
</div> 


<div class="resume right-col" id="ben1">
<p>second text area i need displayed by default</p>
</div> 

<div class="resume right-col" id="ben2">
<p>second text area i need hidden initially/p>
</div> 


<script>
$('.resume') .hide()
$('#ben1').show();
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
$('.resume') .hide()
var target = $(this).attr('href');

$('.resume'+target).toggle();
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

When the page loads, the second div with the id "ben1" is always hidden. Do i need to add something to the script?

Comment: Duplicate `id` are not valid.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a class that shows instead of using the ID, as an example..

```
    <a href="#ben1" class="fa fa fa-times closer" > 
    <p> link text </p>
   </a>
    <a href="#ben2" class="fa fa fa-times closer" > 
    <p> link text </p>
   </a>


<div class="resume right-col class1" id="ben1">
<p>Hello this is a test </p>
</div> 

<div class="resume right-col class2" id="ben2">
<p>Hello this is a test </p>
</div> 


<div class="resume right-col class1" id="ben1">
<p>second text area i need displayed by default</p>
</div> 

<div class="resume right-col class2" id="ben2">
<p>second text area i need hidden initially/p>
</div> 


<script>
$('.resume') .hide()
$('.class1').show();
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
$('.resume') .hide()
var target = $(this).attr('href');

$('.resume'+target).toggle();
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An id should be unique in a page, so you're confusing jquery.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/id/

Try using classes instead.